# Firebase Realtime Database Get Value and Increment

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have firebase realtime database. I have tags and users. When someone clicked the button i want to get like value from tag, increase it and update new value. But i have observer and i cant get updated value with this code:

```
DataService.dataService.TAG_REF.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    self.tags = []

    if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
        for snap in snapshots {
            if let postDictionary = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                let key = snap.key
                let tag = Tag(key: key, dictionary: postDictionary)
                self.tags.insert(tag, at: 0)
            }
        }
    }
    self.dashCollectionView.reloadData()
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

And when i clicked button:

```
if sender.image(for: .normal) == UIImage(named: "like") {
    DataService.dataService.TAG_REF.child(selectedTag.tagKey).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let totalLikeSnap = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        var totalLike = totalLikeSnap["like"] as! Int
        totalLike = totalLike + 1
        DataService.dataService.TAG_REF.child(selectedTag.tagKey).child("like").setValue(totalLike)    
    })

    let likedTags = DataService.dataService.CURRENT_USER_REF.child("likedTags").child(selectedTag.tagKey)
    likedTags.setValue(["time": "getcurrenttimelater"])

    sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "liked"), for: .normal)
    sender.setTitle(String(selectedTag.tagLikes), for: .normal)

    self.dashCollectionView.reloadData()
} else {
    print("already liked")
}
```

But it is not increasing like. I will be happy if anyone help me to update data.

```
tags {
    -bB1231e23a24 {
       comment: 0
       image: "1"
       like: 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Not even in the Firebase Console? Also update your question with your minimal JSON tree

Comment: @Dravidian no it is updating likes in firebase console. But it is not updating from collection view. It updates icon.

Answer (score 2):

First of all change the way you increment your like's in your Database.

```
func updateTotalNoOfPost(completionBlock : (() -> Void)){

 let prntRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("tags/\(selectedTag.tagKey)")

 prntRef.child("like").runTransactionBlock({ (noOfLikes) -> FIRTransactionResult in
    if let totalLikes = noOfLikes.value as? Int{

        noOfLikes.value = totalLikes + 1
        return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(noOfLikes)
    }else{

        return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(noOfLikes)

        }
      }, andCompletionBlock: {(error,completion,snap) in

            print(error?.localizedDescription)
            print(completion)
            print(snap)
        if !completion {

            print("The value wasn't able to Update")
            }else{

            completionBlock()
        }
   })
}
```

There must be an array in which you must be saving your noOfLike's for your collectionView Datasource. When you update your Database, also update your collectionView Datasource.

When your user clicks the button, in your button Function :-

```
updateTotalNoOfLikes{
   print("Value incremented!")

   // Here add the value to your collectionView datasource
    //And then call collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```